# Using Curl in a multithreaded environment on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, curl, signals

I have read that using the curl library (not built with async DNS support I think) in a multithreaded environment on Linux (CentOS) (C++) may cause problems if the CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL option is NOT set to 1.
If I understand this correctly, this is because otherwise a SIGPIPE
signal can be triggered **within another thread**.

I now have the following scenario:
In my main-function (main-thread T1) I have installed a signal-handler
which is ignoring all SIGPIPEs.

```
signal( SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN );
```

At the beginning T1 calls once...

```
curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT );
```

...and then it is using curl permanently this way
(own curl-handle)

```
CURL *curl;
curl = curl_easy_init();
...
...
curlCode = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Then a new Thread T2 is spawning, which is also
using permanent curl in the same way also
with an own handle:

```
CURL *curl;
curl = curl_easy_init();
...
...
curlCode = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

**Question 1:**
Is this code scenario already thread-safe, because the signal handler would ignore ALL SIGPIPEs, including those from T2? When not why?

**Question 2:**
If this code scenario is NOT thread-safe, would adding curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1L) make it thread-safe? Because then the interesting follow-up question, which is not answered anywhere, would be whether it is sufficient to set CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL=1 **only** in T2 (via its own handle) or whether it must be set on **all handles in ALL threads**? Is this option modifying some "global state"? It is very important that I **keep** the timeout functionality in T1 and not get stuck in DNS resolutions for a long time.
T2 is allowed to hang longer. Interesting is also: What happens, If I set CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL=1
to a handle H1 in T1 and CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL=0 to a handle in H2 in T1? Maybe the behavior is completely handle-/instance-bound?